# Can we change destination to a request created on another app?

Tags: uber-api

Even with the `all_trips` scope, it seems we cannot update destination of a request requested by another app?

We are getting a `403: Forbidden` response. Is there any way we can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, there is no way to do this (even with all_trips). Confirmed.

Comment: Do you know if we canceling these rides would fail too?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I thinks so.